# TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I'm stuck with the above error.
The problem come out with the last function "get_student_average".
If "results" store the "get_average(student)" value, why it can't give me back the result of "get_letter_grade(results)"??

```
lloyd = {
    "name": "Lloyd",
    "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
    "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
    "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
}
alice = {
    "name": "Alice",
    "homework": [100.0, 97.0, 98.0, 100.0],
    "quizzes": [98.0, 99.0, 99.0],
    "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
}
tyler = {
    "name": "Tyler",
    "homework": [0.0, 35.0, 45.0, 22.0],
    "quizzes": [0.0, 60.0, 58.0],
    "tests": [65.0, 58.0]
}
students = [lloyd,alice,tyler]
def average(numbers):
    total= sum(numbers)
    total = float(total)
    return total / len(numbers) 

def get_average(student):
    homework= average(student["homework"])
    quizzes= average(student["quizzes"])
    tests= average(student["tests"])
    return 0.1 * homework + 0.3 * quizzes + 0.6 * tests

def get_letter_grade(score):
    if score >= 90:
        return "A"
    elif score >= 80:
        return "B"
    elif score >= 70:
        return "C"
    elif score >= 60:
        return "D"
    else:
        return "F"

def get_student_average(gruppo):
    for student in gruppo:
        results= []
        results.append(get_average(student))
        print (student["name"])
        print (results)
        print (get_letter_grade(results))

get_student_average(students)
```

Comment: you're passing the argument `results`, which is a list, to the method `get_letter_grade`, which expects a numeric value

Comment: Yes I understand it but I have a numeric value inside that list. So how can I solve it? Maybe convert this value before call the function "get_letter_grade"? How?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your intention for the last print statement is to print the letter grade of the student for each iteration. To do that, you should pass the result of the current student to the get_average function, not the current running list of results:

```
def get_student_average(gruppo):
    for student in gruppo:
        results= []
        result = get_average(student)
        results.append(result)
        print (student["name"])
        print (result)
        print (get_letter_grade(result))

get_student_average(students)
```

See if that works for you.

Comment: Yes it works thanks, so I don't need results anymore. But I don't undestand one thing. Inside the foor loop, "result" get the value I'm interesting in but, at any student (loop) doesn't it get more then one value?

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept this answer to let others know it works for this problem.

Comment: @Max `result` is a variable that stores the output of the `get_average` function, which returns only one value. `get_average` takes in a `student` dictionary, from which you calculate average `homework`, `quizzes`, and `tests` scores i.e. 3 values based on the student dictionary's `homework`, `quizzes`, and `tests` list values. The function, then, returns a single value out of those 3 values based on the expression `0.1 * homework + 0.3 * quizzes + 0.6 * tests`.

Answer (score 1):

In `get_student_average()` you are declaring `results` as a list and then you are passing it to `get_letter_grade()`.
`get_letter_grade()` is then comparing a list to a number which is where the `TypeError` is coming from. You have to be sure to send `get_letter_grade()` an int.